# Why is XML validation in a Blazor application giving different messages on localhost and as an Azure Static Web App?

Tags: azure, xsd, xml-validation, blazor-webassembly, azure-static-web-app

***edit***
I made a simplified repo at https://github.com/GilShalit/XMLValidation

---

I am building an XML editor in Blazor WebAssembly (TargetFramework=net5.0).  Part of the functionality involves validating the XML for completeness and according to a complex xsd schema with three includes.

These are the steps I follow:

1. build an XmlSchemaSet and add 4 schemas to it by calling the following method for each xsd:

```
    private async Task loadSchema(string path, string nameSpace)
    {
        byte[] byteArrayS = await _client.GetByteArrayAsync(path);
        Console.WriteLine($"{path}: {byteArrayS.Length}");
        MemoryStream streamS = new MemoryStream(byteArrayS);
        XmlReader xmlSchemaReader = XmlReader.Create(streamS);
        schemaSet.Add(nameSpace, xmlSchemaReader);
    }
```

2. Initializing an event handler with:

```
ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);
```

3. loading the XML into an XmlDocument:

```
        byte[] byteArrayX = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(await _editorTarget.GetValue());
        MemoryStream streamX = new MemoryStream(byteArrayX);
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(streamX);
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(reader);
```

4. validating according to the schemaSet:

```
            document.Schemas = schemaSet;
            document.Validate(eventHandler);
```

ssteps 3 and 4 are run inside a Try...Catch block and running locally when the XML is not well formed (missing closing tag for example), the `document.Load(reader);` line produces an error with a message like the following:

```
The 'publicationStmt1' start tag on line 9 position 11 does not match the end tag of 'publicationStmt'. Line 11, position 12.
```

which is great.  But validating a similar situation in the application deployed to Azure produces the following error message:`Xml_MessageWithErrorPosition, Xml_TagMismatchEx, 11, 12`.

Schema validation errors are caught in the event handler when the line `document.Validate(eventHandler);` is run and a typical message is:

```
The element 'fileDesc' in namespace 'http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0' has invalid child element 'publicationStmt1' in namespace 'http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0'. List of possible elements expected: 'editionStmt, extent, publicationStmt' in namespace 'http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0'.
```

But when run on Azure the message is `Sch_InvalidElementContentExpecting`.

**What could the reason for this difference in the validation results between running locally and in Azure?**

I tried to disable linking by adding:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <BlazorLinkerDescriptor Include="LinkerConfig.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

But that did not make a difference in the deployed application, and running locally with Release instead of Debug did not change anything either.

I also made sure the 4 xsd files are actually loaded when running from Azure.

Comment: When you run in Azure, are you using Blazor Server instead of Blazor WebAssembly?

Comment: No, using WebAssembly on a Static Web App

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this was a feature not a bug...

An [issue](https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/with-blazor-webassembly-xml-validation-errors-are/1356252) I opened on Dev community was picked up by the dotnet/runtime team and added to the GitHub issue tracker [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/49308).

It turns out exception messages are removed to save on size.

Using `<UseSystemResourceKeys>false</UseSystemResourceKeys>` enables exception messages and I must say I am not seeing an increase in size.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Blazor does not include localised error message templates from [System.Xml.Res](https://github.com/rashiph/DecompliedDotNetLibraries/blob/master/System.Xml/System/Xml/Res.cs) class. My guess is Blazor strips it away when building it via your CI/CD pipeline. It's possible your dev machine and build agent have different locales.

I would suggest playing with the following [project properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to try force bundling all cultures and/or loading invariant culture based on `en_US`:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>
<InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization> <!-- If the app doesn't require localization, you may configure the app to support the invariant culture -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

You also mentioned tweaking the [linker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/configure-linker?view=aspnetcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-5.0), but according to documentation it only kicks in for `Release` builds (you seem to not have tried deploying debug version yet). So I would suggest to try deploy a debug build of your app just to eliminate linker completely.

You also could force-link all i18 resources:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <BlazorWebAssemblyI18NAssemblies>all</BlazorWebAssemblyI18NAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and add `System.Xml` to `LinkerConfig.xml` so hopefully it gets served to the client without further optimisations:

```xml
<linker>
  <assembly fullname="System.Xml" />
</linker>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried both your first and second suggestions which made no difference. Questions:  what do you mean by the System.Xml file, and how do I deploy a debug build (on Azure Static Web App through the GitHub deployment process)?